# Dragging PDFs out of safari

Tags: ipad, pdf, ios, ui

Is there a way of dragging an open PDF out of safari into another app without saving it and then having to delete it like to the files app or notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I just found out I have this unanswered question. The solution is to drag out from the URL/Searchbar. You will then not drag the url but the file.